# Transient attribute required

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a transient attribute in my View Object and I want to make in a required field in the model layer. I do not want to use `required` property on view layer to true. I want my validation to be on the model layer. Is there a way to achieve this?
JDev version using: 11.1.17

Answer (score 0):

In 11.1.1.7 Transient attributes cannot be marked "Mandatory." This **is** available in current release 12c.
Regardless, it's better to create a declarative validation that works against the attribute to evaluate it's size (chars or bytes) and then throw a validation error. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/b31974/bcvalidation.htm#ADFFD403) and 7.4.10 How to Validate Against a Number of Bytes or Characters